# How to initialize a write event for all contacts in outlook add in?

Tags: c#, outlook, outlook-addin

I am working on a CRM solution for outlook in c# in Visual Studio.  I have added a ribbon in the inspector window that is used for modifying contact information.  The CRM system (uses a seperate program) determines whether the contact has been edited by checking the contact.User2 field (string).  Currently, when an inspector window is opened for a contact, a write event is initialized for that ContactItem and when the user clicks "save," contact.User2 is set to "true".  This method works perfectly when the information is modified in the full inspector window.  My problem is that when in people view, if the user double clicks a contact, Outlook gives an editable "preview" of the contact's information.  I need a way to set User2 to true whenever a contacts information is saved, not just when a contact window is opened.

I tried the following:
            foreach(Outlook.ContactItem person in searchFolder)
            {
                contact = person;
                contact.Write += new ItemEvents_10_WriteEventHandler(Written);
            }

```
    private void Written(ref Boolean SavePlease)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Written " + contact.FullName);
        //contact.User2 = "true";
    }
```

The messagebox is for debug purposes.  This event will fire once, but will list the first contact in my list's name, not the person I saved info for.
If it is relevant, after an inspector window has been opened for a contact, the write event is initialized and the "preview" view of the contact being saved then sets User2 to true.  Any help or guidance is appreciated, thank you!!  Outlook 2013.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Items.ItemChange event on the Items collection returned from the MAPIFolder.Items property.